# Javascript let a user select a text file and then read the contents from it

Tags: javascript, html, file, text

I'm trying to do basic file input from a text file. I've looked at various posts online and got some of the solution, however, their solution returns a different alert to mine. I want my alert to have the contents of the file in it like theirs does, however mine has a repeat of the file type.

I do not know JQuery, so I would prefer answers in javascript, otherwise I'll struggle to understand.

```js
    function fileSelected(el){
    if(el.files && el.files[0]){
        var f = el.files[0]; 

        if(f){
            var FR = new FileReader();
            FR.onload = function(e) {
                var contents = e.target.result;
                console.log(contents.substr(1, contents.indexOf("n")));
                alert( "Got the file.\n" 
                    +"name: " + f.name + "\n"
                    +"type: " + f.type + "\n"
                    +"size: " + f.size + " bytes \n"
                    + "starts with: " + contents.substr(1, contents.indexOf("n"))
                );
            };       
            FR.readAsDataURL( el.files[0]);
        }

    }   
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Import File Attempt</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href ="style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="file" id="fileChoice" onchange="fileSelected(this)">
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the alert that I did get: 
[Screenshot of my alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRygA.png)

And this is the alert I wanted:
[Alert I wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPu6J.png)

Edit:
Thought to add a screenshot of the text file incase that helps:
[My text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuGxj.png)

Comment: Note that characters in strings are numbered from `0`, so a `substr(1,...)` call gets you a string starting from the second character of the string. That is how it became `ata:...` - originally the data URL starts as `data:...`.

Comment: Side note: as the data URL for a text file luckily starts as `data:text/plai`-***n***, the code can really work with `indexOf('n')`, as it looks for the letter 'n' and finds one. However if you mean looking for a new-line character, it should be `indexOf('\n')`, and also note that it will only show proper results if there is a new-line character in the text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a ***text*** file, I would suggest reading it using [`FileReader.readAsText()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText):

```js
function loadfile(event){
  var fr=new FileReader();
  fr.onload=function(){
    txt.value=fr.result;
  };
  fr.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);
}
```

```css
textarea{
  width: 95%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" accept="text" onchange="loadfile(event)"><br>
<textarea id="txt"></textarea>
```

(`name`-`type`-`size` worked just fine already, so I left them out)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understood the question well. Do you want to read the contents of the file?
For the .txt file:

```
console.log(contents.substr(23,));
```

cut off: data:text/plain;base64, and will display the contents of the file encoded in Base64

check also:

```
var str = "data:text/plain;base64,VGVzdG93YSB0cmXFm8SHCg==";
console.log (str.replace(/^\S+64,/, ''));
```

It will also work for other files than txt
Of course, adapt to your needs.